# Silverlight 4 missing from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: installation, visual-studio

I've just finished installing Visual Studio 2010 professional onto Vista. But don't seem to have Silverlight 4.

If I try to create a new project I can see Silverlight project templates but only seem to be able to target Silverlight 3.

Is Silverlight 4 not part of vs2010 pro by default?

I also noticed the msbuild targets is missing ie the v4.0 folder doesn't exist at the following folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\

Any help/thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Silverlight 4 not part of vs2010 pro by default?

Correct. The SL4 SDK and tools is an add on (and will be available ["in a few hours"](http://twitter.com/scottgu/status/12212062827)).

Update: ["Silverlight Tools Released"](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/15/silverlight-4-tools-released.aspx)

Comment: I should have googled a little harder this page says it all: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/